# Test input made in previous stepper shown in current stepper

Tags: vue.js, cypress

Doing e2e tests, I have to test a stepper form. It is a form with 4 steps. In the first step, some inputs are made, i.e. a username, some numbers, time&date.
In the third step, through some some magic(just doing the tests, not the frontend itself), the inputs of the first step are displayed again, but not as part of the elements that display them. So I cannot do cy.get('foo').contains('bar').

[image: Third stepper displaying input from first stepper]

Here is what inspect gives me

[image: Inspection third stepper]

Any way I can verify with a test that the data displayed here matches the data inut in the first stepper?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, there is a thing called 'shadow dom' - which is not enabled by default in Firefox, the browser I used to inspect (and neither in Electron).

Sneaky bastards hide until you turn on the relevant settings.
For electron(v91):
Cogwheel -> show user agent shadow doms.
Firefox(v93):
about:config in adressbar -> search for devtools.inspector.showAllAnonymousContent and turn it to true

You can then work with them using
https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/shadow